# what is the probability that exactly the same # of tosses will be required for each of the 3 performances?

Tags: probability

Consider an experiment in which a fair coin is tossed until a H is obtained for the first time. If this experiment is performed 3x, what is the probability that exactly the same # of tosses will be required for each of the 3 performances?

Ok so I can see that the probability of having:
3 H's on the first toss = (1/2)^3
3 H's on the second toss = T H 3 times in a row = (1/2*1/2)^3=(1/4)^3
3 H's on the third toss = (1/8)^3

but am unsure on how to continue..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $X_i$ be the number of tosses it takes in performance i, $X_i\geq 1$.

Then, $P(X_i = k) = (1-\frac 12)^{k-1}\frac 12 = (\frac 12)^k$.

And since I assume the three performances are independent from each other, $P(X_1 = X_2 = X_3) = \sum_{k\geq 1} P(X_i = k)^3 = \sum_{k \geq 1} (\tfrac 12)^{3k} = \sum_{k \geq 1} (\tfrac 18)^k = \frac{1}{1-\frac 18}-1 = \frac 17$